# Validation comparing two fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two text fields: Month and Year.

I don't want the user to enter a Month/Year combination that's in the future (ie. greater than the current month/year).

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.month" ng-blur="doThing()" required/>
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.year" ng-blur="doThing()" required/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.doThing = function() {
  if (inFuture) {
    // set form to invalid, blah blah
  }
}
```

This field is already inside of a directive and I'd like to avoid creating an additional directive.

What does `doThing()` have to do to set the form's validity?

Comment: Show us the html for your form, but basically you have to assign a $scope variable to the form and use form validations: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms. You could also add `required="a_scope_variable"` that you would set to `true` or `false` in `doThing()`

Comment: just use ng-change and make a check if the value is according to your needs or not. That would be the easiest solution IMO

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'set the forms validity?' If you want to add a class you could simply set a variable to false, say `$scope.isValid = false;` and then check that prior to submitting your form? You could also set the value of `ng-class` on the input(s) themselves to an expression that uses a different class depending on the value of `$scope.isValid`? Your class could apply a red border, make visible an error message, etc.